# Selecting nth-child in Jquery and conditional formatting not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table and i want to format certain data fields based on their content.  So for example if a field is less than 95% it should be red.

This is the jquery i'm using

```
$(function(){
    $('#ConditionalTable td:nth-child(2n - 4)').each(function(){
        var Sales = $(this).text();
        if (Sales > '95%')  {
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#f76e6e'); 
        } else {
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#99faa0'); 
        }
    });
});
```

It currently selects every second column and turns it green.

However i want it to skip the first 3 columns (these contain titles) and only start applying the formatting from the 4th column.

So the 4th column would have formatting applied then the 6th, 8th etc.

Also for some reason no matter what value is in my table it's being turned green.  So in my code i've said if Sales are greater than 95% it should be green, otherwise red.  But this doesn't seem to be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `#ConditionalTable td:nth-child(2n-4)` to `#ConditionalTable td:nth-child(2n+4)`

```
$(function(){
    $('#ConditionalTable td:nth-child(2n + 4)').each(function(){
        var Sales = parseInt($(this).text().replace('%',''),10);
        if (Sales > 95)  {
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#f76e6e'); 
        } else {
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#99faa0'); 
        }
    });
});
```

The value of n will be `0,1,2,3,.....` in this case it will select `4,6,8,10,.....` children

You can't compare the % values as in the code , so you need to convert it into integer or float and then compare

Comment: Thats great, it colours the correct columns now...
However it still doesnt seem to be working - the columns are being coloured incorrectly.  Using the code above (i've switched the colours around so over 95 is green, under is red.

Everything is coloured in red - except those values between 96% and 99%.  This would be correct if those at 100% were coloured green also but this isn't happening.

Comment: You can't compare as in the code , so you need to convert it into integer and then compare

Comment: Oh wow, well done sir - that fixed it.  Great answer, thanks a million!